# How can I recall the api within activity

Tags: android, rest, api

```
handler = new IncomingHandler();

final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
    .add("day", Integer.toString(dayOfMonth))
    .add("month", Integer.toString(month))
    .add("year", Integer.toString(year))
    .add("hour", "00")
    .add("min", "49")
    .add("lat", "28.4700")
    .add("lon", "77.0300")
    .add("tzone", "5.5")
    .build();
executeAPI("Api name", formBody);
```

I'am changing my date here:

```
 private void changeDate(int number) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, number);
    txtDate.setText(StaticUtils.getDisplayDate(calendar));

}
```

When I changed the date, api has to recall.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can move Request Body to a method inside the class and invoke it within `changeDate()` method

Comment: @Madhan Varadhodiyil: I am calling the api on current date and if i change the date in the method changeDate(),same changes has to be updated in the handler.